Physical phenomena which were "discovered" by mathematics before they were observed
(I am new to this community. If this is off-topic, please let me know and I will close immediately!)
I was watching a Veritasium video on YouTube regarding the novel solution to the Einstein field equations and how the singular solution at the Schwarzschild radius perplexed researchers at first. As it turns out, black holes really do exist and mathematics, an axiomatic system "invented" (although this is potentially controversial) by humans, was used to discover an unbelievable physical anomaly well before it was realized.
Another example I can think of is the discovery of radio waves "discovered" via Maxwell's equations.
What are some other (perhaps less well-known) instances of discovering physical phenomena through theory rather than observation.
I realize that one of the main objectives of theoretical physics is to describe the universe in a language we can understand, and as a consequence things like this probably come up often... I just think this topic is fascinating and sheds some light on the philosophical question of whether mathematics was "invented" or "discovered."

Doesn't every prediction made in the history of physics count as an example?

I was anticipating a response like that. I guess you're right. Perhaps the question is answered in and of itself.

knzhou: No,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe,  black energy,....

The Casimir effect, the positron, the Higgs boson, gravitational waves, the presence of a third generation of quarks (since a 2x2 CKM matrix could not violate CP).

The bending of a light path by a gravitational body predicted by GR before being first observed during an eclipse. The violation of Bell's inequalities.

The prediction of gravitational time dilation around 1907 had to wait nearly 50 years to be confirmed by the Pound Rebka experiment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment Time dilation due to velocity was also predicted before experimental verification.

THe prediction of the positron and anti-matter in general.

The lionshare of fundamental physics research in the modern day seems to consist of predicting the existence of new particles and then performing millions of collision experiments to confirm they exist.

The application of the mathematics of group theory to the properties of the known subatomic particles allowed the later prediction of new particles which had not yet been seen in particle accelerators- but subsequently were.
The mathematical unification of the electromagnetic and weak nuclear forces furnished a prediction of a new force-carrying particle that mediated the propagation of the weak force, which was subsequently found years later in particle accelerator experiments.
The mathematical formalism of wave mechanics, when applied to Maxwell's equations of electromagnetism, predicted the existence of electromagnetic waves that propagated at the speed of light (which had been previously measured) and proved that light itself was an electromagnetic wave.
The invention of non-abelian group theory later furnished the correct logical structure for organizing the particles in the Standard Model of particle physics.
The invention of non-Euclidean geometry later furnished the correct mathematical basis underlying Einstein's formulation of general relativity.
Dirac's reformulation of the Schrodinger wave equation to correctly include special relativity led to the prediction of antiparticles, years before their discovery.
